# What prestige classes will make a cc sorcerer less killable?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, prestige-class, npc, character-advancement

I created a tainted sorceress npc as a friend of one PC. Shes a human sorcerer 4/tainted sorcerer 2 specializing in crowd control and nonlethal damage spells. She is neutral, but because of taint her alignment might change to evil. I am afraid that PC paladin might want to kill her. I wonder what prestige classes with full spellcasting progression could improve her survivability or provide a way to avoid getting oneshoted.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are asking the wrong question here.
First of all, spellcasters focused on crowd control are usually one of the strongest type of spellcasters if not **the** strongest type of spellcasters.

What do you want to know, probably, are what **spells** make a spellcaster less killable at low level.
A brief list is:

- Fly/Spider Climb: (fighters, paladins, rangers, barbarians, etc etc) can't fly without potions, objects, or extremely specific builds. You fly or walk on the ceiling? They can't attack you if they are melee focused characters.
- Invisibility: As fly...except there is no potions since *see invisibility* is a personal spell...so there is even less possibilities they can harm you.
- Distorsion: 50% miss chance on every attack against you.
- Darkness, Fog cloud, etc etc: Everything that create concealment can cause the attacker to miss as per the distorsion spell.
- Many other.

My question, anyway, is: why a paladin want to kill a **neutral** friendly character?

A paladin is not a killing machine. If he think the sorcerer is going on the path of evil...well...he need to help her to stay neutral. Not kill her.
A paladin does not kill every being that results evil to his detect evil. A paladin kill **only** when he **need** to kill if we are talking of humanoid type of characters.
If we are talking of undeads, ofcourse, is another story.

Comment: To note, per RAW, a Paladin cannot associate with evil characters. It is RAW, but it's bad RAW, and I suggest throwing it out and allowing Paladins to try to redeem people if the opportunity arises. But no, a Paladin is not required to kill if they detect evil, and will probably swiftly fall from grace themselves if they do so.

Comment: @NarftheMouse there is a lot of discussion in D&D and pathfinder about this and the general conclusion is that if you (as a paladin) can save the world allying with an evil character you don't lose power. To be clear, anyway, in Pathfinder for example is written a bit better and i suggest to apply that code of conduct

Comment: Yes, that can be a valid reason, provided doing so doesn't cause something worse. ...I have a bit of a grimdark taste in fiction, sometimes.